# iOS AccessoryDetail image doesn't update when reloading UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm loading a UITableView sometimes it will have 5 cells and sometimes 4 cells. Depending on how many cells it will have I want to set the AccessoryDetail button for either row 2 or row 3. I know that the condition works because I've tried it successfully with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` but for some reason the TableView doesn't seem to get updated depending on how many rows that are displayed. I'm reloading the TableView data successfully in `viewWillAppear:`with `[tableView reloadData]` but that doesn't take care of the AccessoryDetail problem for me. I've tried using `[tableView reloadInputViews]`to no avail. The problem is that the AccessoryDetail image is always set to either row 2 or row 3 depending on which view I start to load from the application.

Here's the logic from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
if ((row == 2) && ([[self.office boxAddress] length] == 0) || (row == 3) && ([[self.office boxAddress] length] != 0)) {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        }
```

EDIT:
I've changed my method according to Simon Lee's suggestion with an else clause to look like this but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:OfficeCellIdentifier] autorelease];


 if ((row == 2) && ([[self.office boxAddress] length] == 0) || (row == 3) && ([[self.office boxAddress] length] != 0)) {
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
 //NSLog(@"row == 2 && [[self.office boxAddress] length] == 0 || row == 3");
 } else {
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 }

}
```

Comment: @Please elaborate more your question. Either by posting your cellForRowAtIndexPath method or by posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the if-else statement outside of the if( cell == nil ) block of code. If you're re-using the cell, none of your code is getting called.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:OfficeCellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

 if ((row == 2) && ([[self.office boxAddress] length] == 0) || (row == 3) && ([[self.office boxAddress] length] != 0)) {
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
 } else {
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out myself after some trial and error finally!

Answer (score 1):

You should reset the selection style and accessory type, you have no else clause in there...once you set it, that's it, if you reuse cells they will never get their accessory reset....

Comment: I added the else clause but it doesn't seem to do anything (please see my edit).